# Why textStyle italic is not applied in Android layout for other typefaces than serif?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Below is the simple xml snippet for which `android:textStyle="italic"` is not applying.

If I remove `android:textStyle="italic` the text will appear.

```
<TextView
    android:text="row one"
    android:textSize="15pt"
    android:typeface="serif"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:textColor="#00abcd"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

In the above `android:textStyle="italic"` is working only for `android:typeface="serif"`, if I change the typeface to sans, monospace or normal the `android:text` is not displaying.

Why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try making text italic through strings file it is alternative to this might help you

example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="Row_one"><i>Row one</i></string>
    <string name="Row_two"><i>Row two</i></string>
</resources>
```

Comment: Thats Good thought, but how to set the dynamically changing contents.

Comment: I have the exact same problem : it show correctly on the Eclipse preview (italic) but not on my Galaxy Tab 2 device.

Answer (score 1):

I does not help you, but I have the same problem when setting the Typeface + style in code, but only on certain Samsung devices so it could be device / manufacturer specific.

```
int supportedStyles = Typeface.create(TypeFace.DEFAULT, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC).getStyle();
boolean italicSupported = (supportedStyles & Typeface.ITALIC) != 0;
```

italicSupported always equals true (except for Monospace) but on several Samsung devices (Galaxy II, Note 8) text is not displayed as italic. Nexus 7 is OK, Archos 80 is OK.